# How to downgrade scribus file version?

Tags: scribus, file-conversion

I'm currently using Scribus 1.5.1 development version and I want to downgrade to my 1.4.6 stable version. I want to import paragraph and character styles from my Scribus development file to a new file I make with stable version but there's no style shown which can be selected.

[image: Styles dialog screenshot]

Is there a way to downgrade Scribus file from development to stable version (maybe it's because can't read backward version) or import the styles?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot open a 1.5.x file in 1.4.x.
Nor exchange data in that direction.
Scribus -- like many other programs -- does not provide "forward" compatibility.

Theoretically, you can

- open the 1.5.x .sla file with a text editor,
- browse the xml soup to find out where the styles are defined,
- make a copy of your current 1.4.x file,
- open the copy with a text editor,
- browse the xml soup to find out where the styles are defined,
- paste the 1.5.x styles at the right place,
- tweak the definition of the new styles so that they look like the other ones in the 1.4.x document,
- open the 1.4.x file copy with scribus 1.4.x and hope for the best...

But you will probably be faster by recreating all the styles.

Of course, the other way round -- from 1.4.x to 1.5.x -- you should be able to import the styles.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Yes you right, maybe it's going to be faster if I re-make all my style in 1.4.x version rather than tweaking the file with code editor since it may harm the file itself if I'm wrong in editing the code. I'm not a programmer wizard though. :)